# Stop Chrome Extension from 'stealing' focus from parent page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension has a useful toolbar...and of course a popup.

When a user clicks into some websites, the invokes my Extension (by clicking on the toolbar or just click the Extension icon) focus leaves the element on the parent/main page...which can sometimes be undesirable.

Is there a way to stop a Chrome Extension from taking focus? So the cursor remains blinking and/or the main page element stays in focus and a blur event is not triggered?

Comment: No, you can't do that with the standard popup. You can probably do that if you insert a page element with your UI into the page itself instead of using the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach...since I know which element the user was focused on *before* clicking my popup or toolbar, I simply put the focus *back* on that element after my code ran...works beautifully...